# Issue with exporting PDFs using Tabcmd 2022.1 Error 410

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-file, tableau-api

I have a script that uses tabcmd to pull pdfs each day (at the bottom of this post).

This has been working reliably for a while now but has suddenly stopped working and is giving me the below error.
Nothing has changed within the workbook, and I'm still using the same Tabcmd version (2022.1), so not really sure why it's suddenly stopped.

As I run through 20-30 or so pdfs, it pulls some successfully and then some others fail.
I've ran this loads of times with different changes to test, and even with the same script it seems to be different pdfs that fail each time, with no obvious pattern/consistency.

Has anyone had this issue before or similar, and know the solution/cause?

Thanks,

Liam

Error getting from some of the pdfs:

```
*** Failed to get PDF response due to :
com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.ResponseException: null
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.session.Session.execute(Session.java:555) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.session.Session.execute(Session.java:521) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.VizqlSession.executeCommand(VizqlSession.java:150) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.commands.Export.getPDFResponse(Export.java:210) [classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.commands.Export.export(Export.java:149) [classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.commands.Export.execute(Export.java:100) [classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.Tabcmd.run(Tabcmd.java:295) [classes!/:?]
        at com.tableausoftware.tabcmd.Tabcmd.main(Tabcmd.java:197) [classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app-tabcmd-latest-jar.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app-tabcmd-latest-jar.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [app-tabcmd-latest-jar.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [app-tabcmd-latest-jar.jar:?]
  *** Unexpected response from the server: 410 null
```

TabCMD script in batch file

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\2022.1\extras\Command Line Utility
tabcmd login --server https://eu-west-1a.online.tableau.com/ --username myusername --password mypassword
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i IN (C:\Users\liam\Documents\Config\parameters.csv) DO tabcmd export "Workbook/Report?:refresh=yes%%i" --pdf --pagesize unspecified -f "C:\Users\liam\Documents\PDFs\3%%i.pdf"
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example csv file content and exact layout. Currently your batch file appears to be taking the first sequence of one or more non space or tab characters of every record which does not begin with a semicolon. Is that the intention? because this would only usually be expected if you ware using a TSV, i.e. a tab separated file, not a CSV, i.e. a comma separated file. Even in such cases, you will still have issues with spaces in the first non empty field.

Comment: I don't know anything about how `tabcmd.exe` works but would normally have expected that you'd use `Start tabcmd.exe ...` on line `3` with possibly a short wait before the `for` loop, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 1>NUL`. `tabcmd login...` as you have used, runs that command and only continues with the next command after that command has completed and closed. If as I assume, this is logging into a server, then perhaps you need to run your loop before that server has closed. It would certainly do no harm to try it with the `start` and `timeout` examples.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved. Late last night Tableau themselves identified the issue and shortly after fixed the issue on their end.